# Laravel Form Validations

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I am validating number field below code is working fine. It is checking the characters should not be more then 2 or less, which is fine for me.

```
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'id'    => 'required|min:2|max:2',
        'title' => 'required'
    ];
}
```

But when I add more validation rule like (numeric), min and max validaiton rules get changed, now it is being checked by the numeric number should not be greater than 2... **WHY? IS IT BUG?**

```
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'id'    => 'required|min:2|max:2|numeric',
        'title' => 'required'
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the min and max rule depend on the type of the field. If it is a string it will check the length. If it is a number it will check the value.

So if you want to have numbers only with two chars set use

```
'id'    => 'required|min:10|max:99|numeric',
```

> The field under validation must have a size matching the given value. For string data, value corresponds to the number of characters. For numeric data, value corresponds to a given integer value. For files, size corresponds to the file size in kilobytes.

Comment: What if they try to enter the id like `01`, `02` or `03`?

Comment: I think they will be casted to int (so its 1, 2, 3) and then they will check the min and max.